# How do you install mtop on 12.04 LTS?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'd like to examine some live MySQL queries so have just tried installing `mtop` on a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS box.

However when I try and install it using `apt-get` I get:

```
sudo apt-get install mtop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mtop
```

Given that apt-get returns `Unable to locate` how do I install `mtop` for Ubuntu 12.04?!

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mtop&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Comment: Belongs to http://askubuntu.com (which is part of SE)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

install mytop instead of mtop
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/mytop-top-like-query-monitor-for-mysql.html